# C# - Get file/folder path from treeview node

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 TreeViews in my winform. which contains my computers Drivelists.

Please help me to copy and move selected files/folders from one TreeView to other. I tried to use 2 strings as sourseDir and targetdir to store sourse and target path of my file. I tried to use the below code to access sourse and target path from TreeView nodes

```
string sourcedir = filelistleft.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();
string targetdir = filelistright.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();

foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir))
     File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetdir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
```

But it throws an IOException **The directory name is invalid.**
what can I do?  thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried to debug it and see what are actual filenames passed to `File.Copy`?

Comment: You can at first check what directory names you get that are invalid. It is shown in the exception.

Comment: Is it necessary to add a @ symbol before the file path string?

Comment: What are the values of `sourcedir` and `targetdir` at the moment the exception is thrown?  Are you certain they _are_ valid paths?

Answer (score 1):

I think because the FullPath property returns the node's relative path to tree view root,You'd better store tree view's root path's physical path in a variable, then add the selected node's FullPath to it.

```
string rootNodePhysicalPath = "C\\temp"; //assume c:\temp is tree view's root path
string selectedNodeFullPath  = sourcedir;
string selectedNodePhysicalPath = rootNodePhysicalPath + sourcedir;
```